# Denied accessible config folder in yii2

Tags: .htaccess, yii2, public

So i got this yii2 project, it works fine when i open the URL with http://localhost/myproject/index.php/login/index, but when i open http://localhost/myproject/config/, http://localhost/myproject/uploads/ and http://localhost/myproject/web/access it can access folder inside it.

how can i hide those folder or disable to access it by public?

here is the screenshot how it look like when i open those URL

[image]

i don't know why there is no htaccess in this project (i continue the project from the previous developer)

Comment: "i don't know why there is no htaccess" - Presumably you can create one, can you not?

Comment: it solved, but i don't know how, my devops solve it on server

Comment: By default Yii2 project structure expects you to point the webroot to the `web` folder which contains `index.php`, `.htaccess` and other files and folders that should be accessible directly. That's probably how it's solved on your production server.

Answer (score -2):

at the root of the project add a file called `index.php` with a redirect to the web folder like this

```
<?php
header("location: web/");
?>
```

with this when entering the root you will be redirected to the web folder, which will load your project and you will not see the folder structure

Comment: This won't prevent accessing files in these directories.